# Spring JPA Concurrency Issue with NaturalID

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I cannot wrap my head around the following problem:

If have a JPA Entity with a naturalId consisting of an Enum and a number meaning the combination of type and number have to be unique. No the number expresses the amount of entities of a certain Type I have in the DB.

Now the user X wants to create a new Entity with Type A. The currently highest number in the DB is say 5. Meaning the user will create Type A with number 6. Problem is that user Y might want to create a new entity too. Now I have concurrent access and I don't now how to play this out.

Please note: The user gives me a list of those entities and might request to create 5 Entities of Type A and 2 of Type B (or any other number). This makes it even more complicated if I get 2 of such requests at the same time.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Pessimistic write locking in JPA.

Comment: Use database locks **or** let the database generate the naturalid, (using a sequence for instance) instead of doing a `max(field) + 1)`.

Comment: Generating the key sounds more reasonable to me. I cannot find a way to "reset" the sequence for the second type. What I need is Type A + Number 1, 2, 3 etc. and Type B + Number 1, 2, 3 etc.

Comment: Use a sequence per type.

Comment: I thought about that, yet I couldn't find the JPA way to do it